# A regex that matches strings containing an even number of 0’s or even number of 1’s

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

I need to write a regex that matches strings containing an even number of 0’s or even number of 1’s. (Alphabet Σ= 0,1)

I have already tried `(1*(01*01*)*)|(0*(10*10*)*)` but this can not recognize some strings like the whole string of `11000`. I know that the part `(0*(10*10*)*)` of my regex matches `11000`. But I don't know what's the problem.

Please consider that I can only use `*`, `|`, `?`, range and excluded range.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The set of all binary strings built from the alphabet $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$ can be written as
\begin{align*}
1^{*}\left(01^{*}\right)^{*}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
since each binary string can be grouped into blocks, where each block starts with a $0$ followed by zero or more $1$'s and the word may start with zero or more $1$'s. Symmetrically we can also specify the set of all binary strings as
\begin{align*}
0^{*}\left(10^{*}\right)^{*}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
An even number of $0$s can be assured by doubling each group $01^{*}$ in (1) and symmetrically an even number of $1$s by doubling each group $10^{*}$ in (2).
We so derive OPs regexp stated in the problem.
\begin{align*}
\left(1^{*}\left(01^{*}01^{*}\right)^{*}|0^{*}\left(10^{*}10^{*}\right)^{*}\right)\tag{3}
\end{align*}

> We extend the regexp in (3) by
>
> - enforcing at least one occurrence of an even number of $1$'s resp. $0$'s and
> - we also put zero or more $1$'s at the end of the left-hand alternative of (3) and zero or more $0$'s at the end of the right-hand alternative.
>
> We so obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\left(1^{*}\left(01^{*}01^{*}\right)\left(01^{*}01^{*}\right)^{*}1^{*}\right)|\left(0^{*}\left(10^{*}10^{*}\right)\left(10^{*}10^{*}\right)^{*}0^{*}\right)}
> \end{align*}

*Note:* If we additionally allow the '$+$' quantifier, the regexp can be written as
\begin{align*}
\left(1^{*}\left(01^{*}01^{*}\right)^{+}1^{*}\right)|\left(0^{*}\left(10^{*}10^{*}\right)^{+}0^{*}\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question, @epi163sqrt. But the solution `(1∗(01∗)∗)|(0∗(10∗)∗)` can match `111000` which has odd number of 0's and 1's.  If you meant I should double `10*` and `01*` I get my first answer `(1*(01*01*)*)|(0*(10*10*)*)`.

Comment: @MrUser: Thanks for pointing at this mistake. I've corrected my answer.